# You have reached the maximum number of 10 object references on Activity Assignment

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow that sends an email when an Assignment is added, that meets certain conditions.

When I try to add:

```
NOT(ISPICKVAL(K__ResourcedActivity__r.K__DeliveryGroup__r.K__SalesOpportunity__r.X_Opportunity_Type__c, "Existing Client, Follow on")),
```

To my existing working criteria:

```
AND( 
OR(ISCHANGED(K__Resource__c),ISNEW()), 
NOT(CONTAINS(K__Resource__c,"#")), 
OR((K__Resource__r.K__ResourceType__r.Name = "Associate"),(K__Resource__r.K__ResourceType__r.Name = "Self Employed 1099"),(K__Resource__r.K__ResourceType__r.Name = "Corp2Corp"),(K__Resource__r.K__ResourceType__r.Name = "Employee Hourly/Daily")) 
)
```

I get:

"You have reached the maximum number of 10 object references on Activity Assignment"

My research suggests that Salesforce can increase the limit to 15, which might solve my issue in this instance, but what happens if and when I want to add another clause in the future. I'm guessing I'll be back to square one.

Am I missing something here? If I am restricted so much in the amount of workflows I can create, doesn't this make Salesforce essentially useless?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the limit changes but I'd rewrite your criteria to something like:-

```
AND( 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(K__ResourcedActivity__r.K__DeliveryGroup__r.K__SalesOpportunity__r.X_Opportunity_Type__c, "Existing Client, Follow on")),
OR(ISCHANGED(K__Resource__c),ISNEW()), 
NOT(CONTAINS(K__Resource__c,"#")), 
OR(CONTAINS('|Associate|Self Employed 1099|Corp2Corp|Employee Hourly/Daily|','|'+K__Resource__r.K__ResourceType__r.Name+'|')) 
)
```

And may even add a formula/workflow on to K_*ResourcedActvity*_c which would set a value a boolean to be  K_*ResourcedActivity*_r.K_*DeliveryGroup*_r.K_*SalesOpportunity*_r.X_Opportunity_Type__c=="Existing Client, Follow on" and then just reference the boolean field in your criteria.

Comment: Thanks. Good ideas. Using the '|' didn't solve my maximum references reached problem though.

Comment: Interesting that this didn't work for you; I've used this approach several times for more complex formula than you're using. Weird...

Comment: I think it's actually complaining that my object 'Activity Assignment' has 10 objects references across all my workflows. Which is true and unavoidable. So as far as I can see that means I can't do any more workflows and Salesforce isn't up the job for my company. Or am I missing something?